# LOOP When scraping data

Tags: python, web-scraping

i am trying to scrape data using loop and this is the code

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd

parameters = ['a:1','a:2','a:3','a:4','a:3','a:4','a:5','a:6','a:7','a:8','a:9','a:10']

results = pd.DataFrame()
for item in parameters:
    key, value = item.split(':')
    url = "https://xxxx.000webhostapp.com/getNamesEnc02Motasel2.php?keyword=%s&type=2&limit=%s" %(key, value)
    r = requests.get(url)
    cont = json.loads(r.content)
    temp_df = pd.DataFrame(cont)
    results = results.append(temp_df)

results.to_csv('ScrapeData.csv', index=False)
```

this method is working great but the problem is that there i need the parameters = until 'a:1000' and i think there is a better solution to loop from 'a:1' to 'a:1000' instead of duplicating parameters like in my code .

i really need your help

Comment: Use a `while` loop, make for `value` a counter and your `key`  always `a`.

Comment: is your `key` always equal to `a`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use can use a `for i in range(start, end)` loop. Like this

```
results = pd.DataFrame()
key = 'a'

# Goes from 1 to 1000 (including both)
for value in range(1, 1001):
    url = f'https://xxxx.000webhostapp.com/getNamesEnc02Motasel2.php?keyword={key}&type=2&limit={value}'
    r = requests.get(url)
    cont = json.loads(r.content)
    temp_df = pd.DataFrame(cont)
    results = results.append(temp_df)

results.to_csv('ScrapeData.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: i'm getting error because 'key' is not defined , you cal see url = at the ends contain  %(key, value) , so the keyword will not change only the value need to be from 1 to 1000*

Answer (score 0):

```
value = 1
key = 'a'
while value <= 1000:
    url = .....%(key, str(value))
    ....
    ....
    value += 1

......
```

Use a counter